# Is it possible to persist different file entities with doctrine2 in OneupUploaderBundle?

Tags: symfony, file-upload, doctrine-orm, oneupuploaderbundle

I have many ORM entities which I want to link them to their corresponding files. Example: the entity Motors with MotorsFile, Houses with HousesFile, ...

These ORM entities can be easily definied. This is not a problem. But, my problem is: "Is it possible to define many ORM entities such us MotorsFile and HousesFile while using [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle)?"

I asked this question because processing these uploaded file with doctrine needs creating an event listener to `PostUploadEvent` and `PostPersistEvent`. The event listener would be something like that:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\HelloBundle\EventListener;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent;
use Minn\AdsBundle\Entity\MotorsAdsFile;

class UploadListener
{
    protected $manager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
    {
        $file = $event->getFile();

        $object = new MotorsFile();
        $object->setFilename($file->getPathName());

        $this->manager->persist($object);
        $this->manager->flush();
    }
}
```

But, this code will allow me only to persist one entity (for this example MotorsFile). So, is it possible to specify the uploaded file is corresponding to which entity?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two options.

Given you use different mappings for the different file uploads you can use [generic events](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/events.md) that will be dispatched for each mapping.

After each upload not only the listeners for the `oneup_uploader.post_upload` will be executed, but also the listeners for the special event `oneup_uploader.post_upload.{mapping}`, where `{mapping}` is the configured name in your `config.yml`.

Let's say you have a configuration similar to this one:

```
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
        motors:
            frontend: blueimp
            storage:
                directory: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/motors

        houses:
            frontend: blueimp
            storage:
                directory: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/houses
```

After uploading a file to the `motors` mapping, the generic event `oneup_uploader.post_upload.motors` will be dispatched. The same goes for the `houses` mapping.

If you don't want to use different upload handlers, you could also check for the `type`.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\HelloBundle\EventListener;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent;
use Minn\AdsBundle\Entity\MotorsAdsFile;

class UploadListener
{
    public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
    {
        $type = $this->getType();
    }
}
```

`$type` will be either `motors` or `houses`, depending with which mapping configuration the file was uploaded to the server.